# How to "toDate()" Firestore timestamp's of large documents properly?

Tags: javascript, firebase, timestamp, google-cloud-firestore

Since recently, Firestore returns timestamps not as Date objects, but as Timestamp objects. Meaning, after every query you have to do something like this:

```
// Old:
const date = snapshot.get('created_at');
// New:
const timestamp = snapshot.get('created_at');
const date = timestamp.toDate();
```

I have objects with multiple timestamps stored in them, and I am forced to convert every of these timestamps individually before I can do anything with my object. What I do now is the following:

```
let user = // get user from firestore

user.created = user.created.toDate()
user.lastUpdated = user.lastUpdated.toDate()
user.foo.foo.foo.foo.fooDate1 = user.foo.foo.foo.foo.fooDate1.toDate()
user.foo.foo.foo.fooDate1 = user.foo.foo.foo.fooDate1.toDate()
...
user.foo.fooDate99 = user.foo.fooDate99.toDate()
```

Is there a way around that?

I have to do this with all of my documents, even if I don't need the timestamps to be converted, since various dependencies (e.g. devalue) break with a "Non-POJO" errors when there are raw firestore timestamps in my object.

Is there an option to directly convert all timestamps of a document to normal Date objects, or is the manual way the only option?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no simple option you can toggle to make this happen.

If you don't want to manually change them all, you could write some code to recursively descend all the properties of all your objects, check which ones look like [Timestamp](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.Timestamp) objects (for example, it has a toDate function), and make the conversion if so.

Comment: thanks Doug, that's what I feared. Okay, then that's what I'll do - thanks!